# Projective bundle is stable under twisting by a line bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, fibre-bundles

I want to prove that "Given a bundle $E$, for any line bundle $L$ the projectivizations of $E$ and $E$ tensor $L$ are isomorphic i.e $P(E)≅P(E⊗L)$".

The statement can also be seen on the Wikipedia page of the projective bundle. The reference they give is for Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry. But unfortunately, I am not aware of that.

By bundle, you can as well assume it to be a smooth vector bundle and their projectivization to be a fibre bundle (in the topological sense) with fibre 1-dim subspaces of the vector space fibres.

What I tried:-
At the fibre level, we can define it $[v]→[u⊗v]$ for an arbitrary non-zero element $u$ in the fibre of $L$ and $v$ in the fibre of $E$. This is clearly a well-defined map. Now, how can I get a continuous map at the total space level, at least locally we can do it as we have an explicit description of the projective bundles locally, will this suffice?

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks and regards in advance

Comment: Do you understand how cocycles in $PGL_n$ classify projective bundle? If yes, it's pretty clear that tensoring by a line bundle multiply the corresponding cocycle by a scalar, hence doesn't change it.

Comment: thanks for your response @NicolasHemelsoet but I don't know much about that. Can you suggest something else, Is it possible to explicitly give the map at the total space level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$There's a nice explicit map $P\Hom(L,E)\to P(E)$ that takes a homomorphism to its image. Then use that $E\otimes L \cong \Hom(L^\vee,E)$ where $L^\vee$ is the dual.

But if you work through what this does, it's simply the map $P(E\otimes L)\to P(E)$ that takes $[u\otimes v] \mapsto [u]$ for nonzero $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Can you shed more light on that, What is the precise map that you are talking about?  Also what does it mean when you say $[u\otimes v] \mapsto [u]$ on the total space level? I guess you are implying it for the fiber level, right? @SteveCostenoble

Comment: If you have a nonzero homomorphism $f\colon L\to E$ in a fiber of $\mathrm{Hom}(L,E)$, you can take its image $f(L)\in P(E)$, a line in (a fiber of) $E$. This passes to the projectivization of the Hom bundle. And, yes, I meant everything here as fiberwise.